# Is it possible to verify that washout period was sufficient? And find out if it can be shortened?

Tags: crossover-study

Is it possible to use the data collected during the washout period to verify that the length of the period was sufficient?

The carryover effect was not significant (we did not expect a carryover effect) and there were no effects of treatment.

I am interested in knowing whether the washout period was sufficient, and if I can shorten the washout period for future studies. For example, the washout period was 6 days for a behavioural study. It would save time and money to shorten the period to 4 days when we repeat the study.

I have data collected during the pre-study period (ie a baseline), during the washout periods, and during the periods when treatments were applied.

My thoughts were to compare the washout periods to the pre-study period, since everything was the same except treatments were not applied. To determine whether the washout period was sufficient (1), I would treat the 6 days within each washout period as a random effect. To determine whether I can shorten the washout period to 4 days (2), I would look to see if there are any trends/differences across the days.

However, I wonder if I cannot actually determine whether the washout period was significant because there were no significant effects of treatment.

Comment: I would start by some plotting, maybe time traces ... can you show us some plots?

Comment: I plotted the outcome variable by time (days) with treatments combined and treatments separated. There are no trends - it looks relatively straight across time, with normal/expected variation. The washout periods look similar as well.